# Copying and pasting values in Excel 2016 using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, copy-paste, range

I am a VBA newbie I need help with writing a function that I can call in a formula, the function should copy the values of a cell(This cell should not be a predefined fixed cell instead it should be we must be able to select it while calling the function), and paste them in the cell right next to the cell in which the function is called.

Example:

[image]

In the above function if values in cell B3 & C3 are equal then the formula in cell E3 should call the function "Myfunction()" this function must copy the sum in cell D3 to cell F3, and we must be able to select the cell to copy(myfunction(D3) the D3 can vary it may be E3 or F3 etc)

**My Code:**

```
Dim c As Range
Function myfunction(c)
myfunction = c.Select
Selection.Copy
Range("c" + 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Function
```

The "c" should be variable.

Comment: I do not understand why do you want to have a function to accomplish what you are asking for. Try this `=IF(B3=C3,B3+C3,"")` in cell F3. Do this "kind of" solve your problem?

Comment: HI Prasanna, Thanks for your Reply, actually my problem is far more large than what I asked here, I am a planner and my project involves working on a "Pre-Set" schedule of activities, for this the quantity defined to each activity changes each hour by a fixed rate, once the quantities are equal we have to search and filter out each activity that is 100% and then paste the values manually, otherwise next hour the completion percent will change to more than 100%, for this a macro can work but again the range will be fixed, I just wanted to write a formula that is dynamic in nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and paste them in the cell right next to the cell in which the function is called.

This is not possible, VBA functions called from a formula in the worksheet doesn't have access to any other cell in the worksheet.

---

> Custom functions are not allowed to do anything other than return a value to a formula in a worksheet or to an expression used in another VBA macro or function. For example, custom functions cannot resize windows; edit a formula in a cell; or change the font, color, or pattern options for the text in a cell. If you include “action” code of this kind in a function procedure, the function returns the #VALUE! error.

from [Microsoft Excel UDF guide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-custom-functions-in-Excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f)

Answer (score 0):

As note by Máté Juhász, custom formulas can't alter other cells. Attempting to do so will return a *#VALUE!* error in the cell the formula occupies.

Regarding the first portion (accessing the value of a random cell i.e. D3), you can simply return the *Value* of the source cell Range variable:

```
Function MyFunction(SourceCell As Range)
    MyFunction = SourceCell.Value
End Function
```

This can be use in your original formula `=IF(C3=B3,myfunction(D3),"")`, with that formula being placed directly in e.g. F3. It can also be used in e.g. E3 by changing the value of F3 to `=E3`.

You are (obviously) not limited to one cell - if you wanted to do the inital comparison in the formula itself, you could use `=myfunction(B3, C3, D3)` where the function might look something like:

```
Dim ReturnValue As Variant

Function MyFunction(FirstCell As Range, SecondCell As Range, SourceCell As Range)

    If FirstCell.Value = SecondCell.Value Then
        'If our source is empty, return an error
        If SourceCell.Value = "" Then
            ReturnValue = "Empty Source"
        Else
            ReturnValue = SourceCell.Value
        End If
    Else
        'Our input cells aren't equal
        ReturnValue = "Not Equal"
    End If

    'Return our final value to the cell
    MyFunction = ReturnValue

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Anaksunaman, Thanks for your Reply, actually my project involves working on a "Pre-Set" schedule of activities, for this the quantity defined to each activity changes each hour by a fixed rate, once the quantities are equal we have to search and filter out each activity that is 100% and then paste the values manually, otherwise next hour the completion percent will change to more than 100%, for this a macro can work but again the range will be fixed, I just wanted to write a formula that is dynamic in nature. But "now" I know that UDF's cannot modify cells.